# Race condition concurrent queue - Reference to a pointer

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I am analyzing an implementation of a queue (implemented using a circular buffer) which is supposed to be used by **1** consumer and **n** producers.  This code is a porting of a C# implementation you can find [here](https://pastebin.com/XpHEiph6).

The code below shows the implementation of such a queue, and a `main`. On my system, this program crashes. I narrowed down the problem to the fact that the `pop()` function is returning a reference. Such reference is an alias for the array cell and not for the pointer the cell of the array contains.  This reference is then used to execute the task, but crucially, some producers might write in the same array location and the whole program goes UB. Am I completely going in the wrong direction here?

Of course, if I remove the `&` form the signature the program works fine with no crashes.

I have also used [helgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) to check for race conditions and indeed when I run the reference version it shows a warning.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>


template<typename T, uint64_t SIZE = 4096, uint64_t MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY = 40000000>
class ConcurrentQueue {
private:
    static constexpr unsigned Log2(unsigned n, unsigned p = 0) {
        return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
    }

    static constexpr uint64_t closestExponentOf2(uint64_t x) {
        return (1UL << ((uint64_t) (Log2(SIZE - 1)) + 1));
    }

    static constexpr uint64_t mRingModMask = closestExponentOf2(SIZE) - 1;
    static constexpr uint64_t mSize = closestExponentOf2(SIZE);

    static const T mEmpty;

    T mMem[mSize];
    std::mutex mLock;
    uint64_t mReadPtr = 0;
    uint64_t mWritePtr = 0;

public:
    const T& pop() { //piece of code I believe is dangerous
        if (!peek()) {
            return mEmpty;
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);

        if (!peek()) {
            return mEmpty;
        }

        T& ret = mMem[mReadPtr & mRingModMask];

        mReadPtr++;
        return ret;
    }

    bool peek() const {
        return (mWritePtr != mReadPtr);
    }

    uint64_t getCount() const {
        return mWritePtr > mReadPtr ? mWritePtr - mReadPtr : mReadPtr - mWritePtr;
    }

    bool busyWaitForPush() {
        uint64_t start = 0;
        while (getCount() == mSize) {
            if (start++ > MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void push(const T& pItem) {
        if (!busyWaitForPush()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Concurrent queue full cannot write to it!");
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        mMem[mWritePtr & mRingModMask] = pItem;
        mWritePtr++;
    }

    void push(T&& pItem) {
        if (!busyWaitForPush()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Concurrent queue full cannot write to it!");
        }

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        mMem[mWritePtr & mRingModMask] = std::move(pItem);
        mWritePtr++;
    }
};

template<typename T, uint64_t SIZE, uint64_t MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY>
const T ConcurrentQueue<T, SIZE, MAX_SPIN_ON_BUSY>::mEmpty = T{ };

int main(int, char**) {
    using Functor = std::function<void()>;

    ConcurrentQueue<Functor*> queue;

    std::thread consumer([ & ] {
        while (true) {
            if (queue.peek()) {
                auto task = queue.pop();
                (*task)();
                delete task;
            }
        }
    });

    std::thread producer([ & ] {
        uint64_t counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            auto taskId = counter++;
            auto newTask = new Functor([ = ] {
                std::cout << "Running task " << taskId << std::endl << std::flush;
            });
            queue.push(newTask);
        }
    });

    consumer.join();
    producer.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if the function returns a reference, behaviour will be undefined if the reference is subsequently used and another thread may change what element/cell is referred to.    Essentially, be returning a reference, you have introduced a need for the caller of `pop()` to take care of synchronisation with the producers - in your code, by using the mutex `mLock`.   There is a need for synchronisation with other functions as well

Comment: You also have problems with `peek` and `getCount`. Make your "Ptr" members atomic.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes the problem is that the write and read on the Ptr variables is not atomic and the `getCount` for instance can execute while another thread is updating them. This also causes UB. I did not want to pollute the question with too many info.

Comment: So probably you need to ask yourself if the C# code is broken also.  I'm not a C# expert....

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It is probably also broken in the sense that the access to the ptrs variable is not atomic. I do not think it suffer from the reference problem too. But I am also no expert in C#.... I was hoping some of you is :D